# python asyncio connection gets incomplete http response

Tags: python, sockets, http, python-asyncio

I was trying to get the content of website with python asyncio.

```
import asyncio
import urllib.parse

@asyncio.coroutine
def get(url):
    url = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
    connect = asyncio.open_connection(url.hostname, 80)
    reader, writer = yield from connect
    request = ('HEAD {path} HTTP/1.1\r\n'
             'Host: {hostname}\r\n'
             'Accept:*/*\r\n'
             '\r\n').format(path=url.path or '/', hostname=url.hostname)
    writer.write(request.encode('latin-1'))
    response = yield from reader.read()
    print(response)
    writer.close()

url = 'http://www.example.com'
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = asyncio.ensure_future(get(url))
loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
loop.close()
```

It gets only the header, but no content!

```
b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nCache-Control: max-age=604800\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nDate: Sat, 25 Feb 2017 11:44:26 GMT\r\nEtag: "359670651+ident"\r\nExpires: Sat, 04 Mar 2017 11:44:26 GMT\r\nLast-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT\r\nServer: ECS (rhv/818F)\r\nX-Cache: HIT\r\nContent-Length: 1270\r\n\r\n'
```

Comment: You're making a HEAD request, what did you expect?

Comment: @jonrsharpe great answer, mate. He most probably did it by mistake, did you downvote the question too? It would be more helpful if you have explained him that a HEAD request just gathers the heads from the website, while he'd be looking for a GET request instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by one of the comments, you are performing a HEAD request instead of a GET request: a HEAD request will only retrieve the headers, that's why you are only receiving those.

I've tested your code with GET instead of HEAD, and it works as you were expecting; but as an advice, I'd be moving to aiohttp, your entire code would be comprised into the one below, not only nicer looking, but also way faster:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def get(loop, url):
    async with aiohttp.request('GET', url, encoding='latin-1') as response:
        html = await response.text()
        print(html)

url = 'http://www.example.com'
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(get(loop, url))
loop.close()
```

NOTE: This is Python 3.5+ async/await style, but it can be easily translated into 3.4 with @asyncio.coroutine and yield from. Let me know if you have any issue doing it.

Comment: It works! Thank you. My script was modified from an example in python document. It looks like that I forgot to change HEAD to GET.

Comment: Glad to be of help to you.